# read line by line using `for` loop

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

How can I read line by line using `for` loop?

what I've tried:

```
hh=$(echo -e "\n1\n2\n3\n4\n")

IFS=$'\n';

for r in "$hh"; do echo $r; done
1 2 3 4

echo -e "$hh"

1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Tell us more about the problem you're trying to solve.  Your [comment below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279911/read-line-by-line-using-for-loop#comment32067493_21279957) mentions large files.  The above is an exercise in [word splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though using `while read` is definitely can solve this but if you really want to use `for loop` then you need to use `IFS=$'\n'` to read your input string in the `bash's for loop`:

```
hh=$(echo -e "\nname n1\nval n2\n3\nfoo n4\n")
IFS=$'\n' && for r in $hh; do echo "r='$r'"; done
r='name n1'
r='val n2'
r='3'
r='foo n4'
```

Comment: change to `echo "t $r"` you will see it echos only once

Comment: @anubhava  there's still a problem. It would not work when a line contains many words. what it would do is to pring word by word. that's why you need `IFS=$'\n';` which apperntly doesn't work

Comment: @Orlo: Got your point. I updated my answer as per your comments, check it out.

Comment: I think this answer is misleading, because @Orio's original issue is that the for loop was only executed once, quoting $r has no effect on the expansion of $hh

Comment: @XTian: Updated, that description was left over from my original attempt.

Comment: your printf, merely appends another \n to the variable, it is infact because you are missing the quotes around the result, that the variable gets expanded correctly, so the answer is, $hh should not be quoted. Check out my fix 2

Comment: I am down-voting this answer because it states that printf is required, which is incorrect. the only reason this solution works is because there are no quotes around `$(printf "%s\n" "$hh")`, if you put quotes around then this fails just like the original post.

Comment: @XTian: Yes agreed, printf wasn't really needed and if you see edited history you will see how it was before this. I rolled it back to my previous version since that was more correct.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `while` loop:

```
$ while read -r r; do echo $r; done <<< "$hh"

1
2
3
4
```

Comment: sure, but I need `for` loop

Comment: @Orlo Why is `for` needed? The answer here is a very common idiom.

Comment: @BroSlow Yes someone downvoted this.  Unfortunately didn't care to tell what was wrong.

Comment: @Orlo Why do you _specifically_ need a `for` loop here?

Comment: @devnull I'm working with large files. I know I can use while, awk and probably other methods.

Comment: @Orlo It might help to understand what exactly are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Orlo Large files are a good reason **not** to use a for loop.  It requires that the text gets expanded and split before the loop even starts.  It may require the shell to allocate twice or even thrice the size of the text in memory.

Comment: Another reason not to use `for`: the input tokens are subject to globbing; e.g., a line containing just `*` would expand to the names of the files and subdirectories in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is, you *don't* read line-by-line with a for loop. Use a while loop instead with the `read` builtin:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done <<< "$hh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from around `$hh` and the original code works fine:

```
hh=$(echo -e "\n1\n2\n3\n4\n")
IFS=$'\n'
for r in $hh; do echo "Value: $r"; done

# output:
Value: 1
Value: 2
Value: 3
Value: 4
```

Answer (score -1):

It's only the expansion of the $hh variable in the for loop that DOES NOT need quoting.

This code works.

```
hh=$(echo -e "\n1\n2\n3\n4\n")

echo "Starting string"
echo -e "$hh"

IFS=$'\n';

echo "Original Code"
for r in "$hh"; do echo r is $r; done



echo "Fixed Code 1"

IFS=$'\n';

for r in "$hh"; do echo r is "$r"; done


echo "Fixed Code 2"

IFS=$'\n';

for r in $hh ; do echo r is $r ; done
```

And produces,

```
Starting string

1
2
3
4
Original Code
r is 1 2 3 4
Fixed Code 1
r is 
1
2
3
4
Fixed Code 2
r is 1
r is 2
r is 3
r is 4
```

Comment: My answer was wrongish, despite producing the correct output. Your answer does not produce correct output. $r needs to be quoted, otherwise it will remove any empty lines and mess up escapes given your IFS, similar to how `a="  a   b   c   "; echo $a` prints `a b c`.

Comment: Also the same reason "$hh" needs to be quoted. However that loop over the string correctly, which is why in my opinion, only working answer so far is `devnull`'s

Comment: Multiple sequence of field separators do get folded into one separator, this is a characteristic of a field separator. OP's issue was he only had one echo, my FIX 2 gives him 4 echos quoting $r does not change this. I think you are thinking about his next problem maybe.

Comment: Quoting $r doesn't change it, because not quoting $hh already broke it. So it's not printing the string correctly.